# Kubernetes pods cannot access HTTPS sites

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, containers, calico, kubespray

Just installed Kubernetes cluster using `kubespray`. `3 master` nodes and `3 worker` nodes + `2 haproxy` nodes in front of master nodes with `keepalived`.

Everything works perfectly except for one thing.
When I try to update packages on `alpine` or `ubuntu` inside pods:

```
Ign:1 https://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease          
Ign:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                
Err:4 https://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates Release                            
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.
```

Quick debugging revealed that I'm getting self-signed Traefik Default certificate from proxy in K8s

```sh
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername gnupg.org -connect gnupg.org:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text
```

Output:

```
       Issuer: CN = TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 15 14:08:39 2020 GMT
            Not After : Jun 15 14:08:39 2021 GMT
        Subject: CN = TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
```

Is there a way to disable SSL termination?

My installation is a completely fresh install of `kubespray` from `master` branch

Kubernetes version: `v1.18.5`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are proxying outgoing connections? Also, how did you configure your nodes to use an outgoing proxy?

Comment: That's the thing that I'm not proxying outgoing connetions it is somehow by default. Outgoing nodes do not use any proxy and able to perform update, upgrade & access https endpoins. Is there a way to check proxy settings on pods ?

Comment: Check that your DNS isn't returning garbage?

Comment: are you sure its an SSL problem and not a general network/egress issue? Are you able to curl an http url successfully?

Comment: Just checked. Nslooked up inside the containers. Returned same IP from the node and the laptop. But strangely authority address is 169.254.25.10. All cluster pods are in 10.233.80.0 network

Comment: @bri Yes, I can `wget` the content of a web page via http. VIa https `wget -qO- https://google.com` I also get the response successfully. But with the message in wgets response: wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented.

Comment: Doesn't look like a GPG keychain issue at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an issue in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
`search` list had a domain that was pointing to a server with traefik on it.
That domain's DNS zone had `*.domain.com` record in it. So that was the problem.